# When should I use anyObject insted of UIButton in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ibaction, anyobject

When should I use anyObject insted of UIButton in swift?
I am making an IBAction for my button that will be used to do more than on task on of the tasks is to switch to the next view.

Comment: See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475178/whats-the-difference-between-anyobject-and-uibutton-as-sender)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ultimately, it really doesn't matter.

You can choose to use the parameter of `(sender: AnyObject)` or you can use `(sender: UIButton)`.

There might be times however where you might have to cast `AnyObject` as a `UIButton` if you need access to the properties provided by `UIButton`.

For example let's say you have and you want the button to disappear after it is clicked.

```
func doSomething(sender: AnyObject) {
    let button: UIButton = sender as! UIButton
    button.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of using an abstract AnyObject type for an IBAction may be advantage for a situation in which you have multiple UI objects that should trigger the same action.  An example of this would be if you wanted to have a button and a gesture recognizer share the functionality of a common action.  Even with a shared action, it would be possible to have different execution paths for the two objects.