# Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'tag'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I added a button on my custom tableViewCell and i want that after the button is tapped it pass data according to the cell on which the button is located, so to find out on which cell is the button i added a tag, but i'm getting this error

[image]

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToLast" && sender is IndexPath {


             let dvc = segue.destination as! FinalClass 
            dvc.index = (sender as! IndexPath).row
            dvc.places = sortedArray
            dvc.userLocation = currentLocation

            }
        if segue.identifier == "goToReview" {

            let index3 = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
            let rev = segue.destination as! ReviewClass


        }

}
```

How can i adjust it?

(`cell.reviewButton.tag = indexPath.row`) this is the tag i added in my cellForRowAt

UPDATE

this is the button action in my VC

```
  @IBAction func ReviewButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {

      performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToReview" , sender: self)
    }
```

and this is the outlet in my custom tableViewCell class

```
 @IBOutlet weak var reviewButton: UIButton!
```

i do not understand how can i associate this button with

```
else if segue.identifier == "goToReview", let button = sender as? UIButton, let rev = segue.destination as? ReviewClass {
            let index3 = IndexPath(row: button.tag, section: 0)
```

Comment: Convert sender to button [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972807/when-should-i-use-anyobject-insted-of-uibutton-in-swift), then get the button tag.

Comment: Even you can store the selected index globally when user tapped button instead of getting the index in segue. It the proper way to do code.

Comment: you need to cast to UIButton and then you should be able to use the .tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force downcast the optional `Any` to expected `UIButton` and `IndexPath` and use an `else` clause instead of `if` twice

```
 if segue.identifier == "goToLast" {
        let dvc = segue.destination as! FinalClass 
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        dvc.index = indexPath.row
        dvc.places = sortedArray
        dvc.userLocation = currentLocation
}
else if segue.identifier == "goToReview" {
        let button = sender as! UIButton
        let index3 = IndexPath(row: button.tag, section: 0)
        let rev = segue.destination as! ReviewClass
}
```

or use a `switch`

```
 switch segue.identifier {
     case "goToLast":
        let dvc = segue.destination as! FinalClass 
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        dvc.index = indexPath.row
        dvc.places = sortedArray
        dvc.userLocation = currentLocation

    case "goToReview":
        let button = sender as! UIButton
        let index3 = IndexPath(row: button.tag, section: 0)
        let rev = segue.destination as! ReviewClass

    default: break
}
```

The code **must not** crash. If it does you made a design mistake.

**Edit**

You have to pass the `UIButton` instance (the `sender`) from the `IBAction` to the `sender` parameter of `performSegue`. The outlet is irrelevant.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToReview" , sender: sender)
```

Comment: ok but a question,  
    @IBAction func ReviewButtonTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToReview" , sender: self)
    }         this is my button, i have also to define an outlet? How can the compiler associate let button to this function?

Comment: I'm assuming that somewhere you are calling `performSegue` and pass the identifier and the button.

Answer (score 1):

It is common you will provide a sender as `Any` in your method in cases where it can be different object. In such case you will need to typecast it to a specific object which is best done as `let button = sender as? UIButton` in swift.

By doing so you will receive an optional value and its tag would be `button?.tag` and its type `Int?` which then again disallows you to create an index path.

So a proper way for this method should be as follows:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToLast", let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
            let dvc = segue.destination as! FinalClass 
            dvc.index = indexPath.row
            dvc.places = sortedArray
            dvc.userLocation = currentLocation
    } else if segue.identifier == "goToReview", let button = sender as? UIButton {
            let index3 = IndexPath(row: button.tag, section: 0)
            let rev = segue.destination as! ReviewClass
    }
}
```

Note that I have changed both `if` statements and managed to even remove an extra force-unwrap (The `!` thing). If you don't mind force-unwrapping which crashes your app when incorrect then you could as well just do:

```
let index3 = IndexPath(row: (sender as! UIButton).tag, section: 0)
```

But I suggest you avoid all force-unwrapping to improve stability. For your case that would be:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToLast", let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath, let dvc = segue.destination as? FinalClass  {
            dvc.index = indexPath.row
            dvc.places = sortedArray
            dvc.userLocation = currentLocation
    } else if segue.identifier == "goToReview", let button = sender as? UIButton, let rev = segue.destination as? ReviewClass {
            let index3 = IndexPath(row: button.tag, section: 0)
    } else {
         print("ERROR: Incorrect configuration!") // Put a breakpoint here and analyze what was the identifier and what the sender so none of the statements were hit
    }
}
```

Comment: Force unwrapping is perfectly fine (and even recommended) in this case. It will reveal a **design error** if it crashes. The code **must not** crash if everything is hooked up properly in Interface Builder. With your first syntax in the worst case the code does nothing (the segues are not performed) and you have no idea why.

Comment: Matic i updated the question because i do not understand  a thing

Comment: @vadian Agreed completely on this case, that is why I posted both versions and on the non-crashing one added the print of the error just so you know this is what happened. But I will not agree this is generally what you should do. An outlet may not be installed for some configuration or it was deprecated for instance and should be checked. You can trust my word that in continuous development you are better of avoiding force-unwrapping.

Comment: @fisherM The edited part of your question seems to have nothing to do with the original. As vadian already updated you need to send the button instead of "self" into the call to perform performSegue. As for "not understanding a thing" it might be good for you to look at some tutorial or something that covers the raw basics of iOS application development.

Answer (score 0):

You can get UIButton object from sender then UIButton object have tag property to access.

```
let button = sender as? UIButton
let index3 = IndexPath(row: button?.tag ?? 0, section: 0)
```

Comment: You can't have optional integer in index path. So maybe `IndexPath(row: button?.tag ?? 0, section: 0)` which will default to 0. But that makes no sense, it is an exception that needs to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to change your segue method with below method

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToLast" && sender is IndexPath {


         let dvc = segue.destination as! FinalClass 
        dvc.index = (sender as! IndexPath).row
        dvc.places = sortedArray
        dvc.userLocation = currentLocation

        }
    if segue.identifier == "goToReview" {

        let index3 = IndexPath(row: (sender as! UIButton).tag, section: 0)
        let rev = segue.destination as! ReviewClass


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For manage this problem first you need to first assign tag of button in cell for row which is you already done.

```
cell.reviewButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

After that you can add target actions on your button in the cell for row

```
cell.reviewButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self. 
func_Navigate(_:)), for:UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Out side cell for row make implement one function like that:-

```
@IBAction func func_Navigate(_ sender: UIButton)
{

If sender.tag == 0

 {

    \\ here sender.tag = 0 means button belong from fist row of your table view. you can perform navigation like that :-
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast", sender: self)

}
else If sender.tag == 1

{
    \\ here sender.tag = 1 means button belong from second row of your table view. you can perform navigation like that :-
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToReview", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: ok so inside the action of func navigate i'll add performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToReview" , sender: sender)  right? and in my func prepare how can i tell on which row the button has been pressed ?